# Changing the color of the input value? jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I want to change the text color inside the input field. Color of those input words that are input by the users & color the default color.

Here's the jQuery Code:

```
var default_email_val = 'Enter Your E-Mail';

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type="email"]').attr('value', default_email_val).focus(function(){
        if($(this).val()==default_email_val){
            $(this).attr('value', '');
        }
    }).blur(function(){
        if($(this).val()== ''){
            $(this).attr('value', default_email_val);
        }
    });
});
```

**I want to change the color, of the text field to grey when the page loads & when the user input some words, I want to keep those words with a black color, Using CSS or any other method.**

How can I do that?

Comment: HTML5 has a very nifty placeholder attribute that does all this for you ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell from the provided jQuery you want a placeholder functionality. This already exists in HTML5.

Just create an input with the `placeholder` attribute:

```
<input placeholder="Enter your E-mail" type="text">
```

[See here more on the placeholder attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_placeholder.asp)

Comment: Thanks man , it really helped me! I spin my head with jQuery doing that thing. :)

Answer (score 0):

consider using jquery method `.css()`

```
$(this).css("background-color","#cccccc");
```